# Eclipse - How to add subfolder to end of XAMPP localhost

Tags: php, eclipse, xampp, eclipse-pdt

a quick question about running PHP applications in Eclipse PDT. I have done a lot of searching but can not find what I am looking for.

I have XAMPP installed and am trying to run my PHP applications out of eclipse. The problem is I have my source files in a SUBFOLDER of the htdocs folder. So when I run, eclipse nagivates to:

```
http://localhost/index.php
```

But I need it to navigate to:

```
http://localhost/MyWebApps/index.php
```

Is there any way I can set the PHP server to always default to MyWebApps folder in eclipse? As MyWebApps is my eclipse workspace.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here 3 solutions:

**First** way, easy for one file. Project Explorer -> Right click on file -> Run As... -> Run Configurations. Configure similar to screenshot:
[image: config]
Then, click (V) arrow after run button in toolbar and choose configuration, "New configuration A" as in example.

**Another** better way: (root needed)

1. Add host "127.0.0.1 *mywebaps.localhost*" to /etc/hosts
2. Configure VirtualHost *mywebaps.localhost* in Apache, with document root point     to your Workspace (files starting with "." should be blocked for this and nested directories, this is eclipse meta files)
3. Configure web server in eclipse to use *mywebaps.localhost* as host
   name, then your file will be opened as
   *http://mywebaps.localhost/projectname/index.php*

**And** finally, easy way: (root may be needed)

1. Leave your Workspace folder inaccessible by apache.
2. Create new php project, not in workspace but in apache document root
   folder(should be writeable by user)